# Creating a force directional visualisation of how pages link to each other in a mediawki installation

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, data-visualization

I have a MediaWiki installation, and I would like to create a force-directional style visualisation of which pages connect to each other. The MediaWiki installation is not *very* big, under about 100 pages.

Any ideas on where to start? I would, ideally, not like to use JQuery.

I did a Google search, but I do not really have a clue of what to do first.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, then it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [this one](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/force.html) ?

[D3.js](http://d3js.org/) is a great library to work with

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be what I need. Is there an option to include text with the nodes?

Comment: Yes, doesn't seem to have any documentation or comments, but I can play around with it (I think). If I have any problems, then I shall post again here. Thank you!