# I can't use backspace in a javascript-generated input text box

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I made a javascript-generated form that produces buttons and 1 `input type='text`. However, in order to delete what you've typed, you need to highlight the text and type over it, instead of the easy BACKSPACE key. Here is some of my code:

```
var imTime=document.createElement('button');
var imDaTime=document.createElement('input');
imTime.setAttribute('onclick','xSetDaTime();');
imDaTime.setAttribute('type','text');
imDaTime.setAttribute('id','daT');
imTime.innerHTML='Set time (in seconds) : ';
document.body.insertBefore(imDaTime,document.body.firstChild);
document.body.insertBefore(imTime,document.body.firstChild);
function xSetDaTime() {
    lingDRILL.startTime=(new Date()).getTime()-((document.getElementById('daT').value)*1000);
}
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Everything works properly, with the exception of the backspace/delete key.

Comment: Working fine for me have a look http://jsbin.com/ayegay/edit#preview

Comment: do you have other javascript on the page that could be interfering with it?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found out why it isn't working. The script was supposed to be for injecting onto a website to make it more user-friendly. It turns out, however, that they turned off the ability to use backspace. I used a different input instead.

Comment: Not for me... still another 23 hours

Comment: Then how come I was able to accept an answer on this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331747/creating-a-force-directional-visualisation-of-how-pages-link-to-each-other-in-a? I only asked it yesterday